# My fittonia doesn't feel so good - what could be the issue?

Tags: terrarium

Last Christmas
in twenty twentytwo,
I gifted my daughter
a small terrarium.

The little leaflet that came with it didn't specify what plant it was, but it looks a lot like a fittonia (nerve plant). We tried our best to make it happy, but it always seemed like it was somewhat suffering. The leaves have always been a little curved, a little limp and pale (they were fine when I bought it). Lately however it's looking worse than ever and even watering doesn't help anymore.

The first culprit should be lighting, although the internet can't agree whether it's too little or too much. In any case, that hasn't changed recently - the plant is in our sunniest window (which doesn't get any direct sunlight anyway), plus we've set up a small white (6000K) table lamp pointing at it (turned on more than 12 hours a day).

Any ideas what's going on here and how to help it?

[image: Without lid]
[image: With lid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plant has been kept too wet due to lack of drainage and in light levels that are too low.
I recommend:

- cut one third of the foliage back to a node above the surface once every three months. Stop when it looks better.
- remove the decorative pebbles so you can tell when it is dry
- moving it closer to natural light ( A filtered east or north exposure). The plant is probably getting less than 100 lux and outside on  a summer day can be 100,000 lux. This plant would be happier at 250 lux with ventilation.
- Once you see new growth try some very dilute 20-20-20 fertilizer every other week for a month.

Sometimes people do things with plants that are pretty but not sustainable.  This is one of those examples.

- You need a moisture meter to tell how wet the soil is but it is easy to get a wrong reading as the soil is not deep.
- the terrarium top means no moisture is lost but encourages the growth of algae and moss
- plants need light to grow but the heat can build up inside a terrarium exposed to hot direct sun.

Comment: Yeah! This is the best fix. As also, I'd prefer to add plant food/micronutrients post 2 weeks of it's transplantation into normal soil. The peat moss used as a substrate here is void of all nutrients and benefecial microbes that normal soil would elsewhere provide.

Comment: Whoa, this is a lot to take in. :) OK, in turn now... the water - the idea for the terrarium was that it's kinda self-sustaining and need little maintenance. The water needed to be refilled, but infrequently. The lid keeps the water in and provides the wet air that the plant needs (otherwise the winter air is very dry here in Latvia). Of course it's possible to overwater it... how do I tell how much water is enough? The soil is covered with decorative pebbles, I can't even stick my finger in it.

Comment: Cutting it back - do you mean to cut off some leaves and stems? How do I choose what to cut and what to keep?

Comment: Light - well, most light comes from natural sources (the window). The lamp is just a supplement. It's just that it's winter here and almost perpetually cloudy. Otherwise the plant is already getting as much as is possible... Is there a way perhaps to measure how much light it's getting? Cell phone sensors come to mind - you can measure light brightness with the right app. Any idea what number I should be aiming for?

Comment: @Vilx- edited and expanded my answer.  I would not bother trying to measure light as you can only provide what windows allow.  Put it right next to a north or east window

Comment: @kevinskio - That's where we're keeping it - on the windowsill. Plus the lamp next to it, for a few extra lumens. OK, I guess the light is probably fine. I opened it up and after some serious scientific investigation and rigorous testing I have determined that the technical name for the soil status in the terrarium is "drenched". Yeah... OK, no more questions, my bad. I'll leave it without the lid for a few days to try and dry it out.

Comment: I was always worried about removing the lid for long because the air in our home is almost always very dry, especially now in the winter. If there's one thing that every article about fittonia mentions, it's that it needs the kind of humid air you only get in tropical rainforests after a thunderstorm. So I was more afraid that it might be too dry, and never considered if it might be too wet...